# Reproject rectangle from latlon to metres

Tags: geometry, coordinates, transform, jts

I have this **bounding box** expressed in **latlong**:

```
POLYGON ((51.2913 -13.5599, 51.2913 13.1589, 
35.0325 13.1589, 35.0325 -13.5599, 51.2913 -13.5599))

widthDeg="26.7188" heightDeg="16.2588" areaDeg="434.4156254400001"
```

I'd like to get the equivalent width/height/area in **metres**.
I found this formula:

```
1 degree of longitude = 60 * 1.852 km * cos (latitude)
```

How can I use this to translate the bounding box? Is this a valid approximation?

Thanks for any hints!
Mulone

Answer (score 0):

The width in metres may be different at the north and south sides of the bounding box; unless your box is guaranteed to be quite small in latitude, you probably don't really want to try to describe it with a height and width in metres.

The area is well defined, though; you can find a formula at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223110143/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/63767.html): it's equivalent to |sin(lat1)-sin(lat2)| * |long1-long2| * R^2 if you measure your longitudes in radians. (Multiply by pi/180 if they're in degrees, and don't forget to convert them to radians before passing them to the sine function in that case.) Here R is the radius of the earth, which is approximately 6400km; more accurately 6371km; if you think you need it more accurately than that, remember that the earth isn't really a sphere and think again.